# Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is not allowed by Access Control Origin in Safari

Tags: node.js, cors, angular10

For an Angular 10 application that I am running, I am getting the following error when the page loads in Safari. (working fine for Chrome and Firefox).

```
Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control_origin
```

[CORS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAWwh.jpg)

I have tried the following solutions to resolve this. But none of them seems to work.

1. In `server.ts` I am setting the headers as follows:-

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

2. I have also tried the follows:-

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

3. I have also tried this, by clearing browser cache and cookies.

None of these seems to work.
Can any one help me with this?

4. List item

Comment: You could use this [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041247/11644167). It will solve your problem!

Answer (score -1):

From [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824661/cors-request-not-working-in-safari) it seems, that adding `Accept-Language` inside `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` should resolve the problem.

Comment: I tried this. 
```res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept-Language, Accept");
``` 

It doesn't seem to work. :(